# How do I decrease an Integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a server which uses a MySQL database for storing users. I have an integer as the primary key. The integer is the primary key and with auto increment.

The problem is when registration fails (on the website provided by my server) the integer still increases by **1**, which means: if a user succeeds in signing up, the user will get the id of one. Just as it should be. However, if a user then fails to register (the username already being taken for example), and then succeeds to register the user will get the id of 3.

I am looking for syntax like: `UserId--` or `UserId = Userid - 1`.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Comment: Don't store the username before the registration succeed.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal The usernames aren’t the problem. Please read the question again.

Comment: @MoltasDev During the registration process.. you are saving the data in database that's why it increment automatically... in case of a fail..the data should not be saved in database... That way the auto increament will not increase the ID... You might be having some problem with the process or code... We can't be sure until/unless you share the code... As far as I can say... This could be the only reason..since the `UserID` will auto increase only when the data is stored...

Comment: @HimanshuBansal The way my server knows it was a fail is through he response the MySQL server gives. I other words: I have to try to register a user to know whether or not it was a success. I suppose it could be done in some other way but that would be a more tedious process than simply decreasing the value of the UserID if a register attempt fails.

Comment: @MoltasDev :P If you can tell me.. if the registration fail.. does it store the failed user data in database? The step wise process should be this.. `1). user enter data 2). save to database(increase user_id) 3). return success`... and in case of fail `1). User enter 2). return fail`. Can you explain the step wise process and the conditions on which registration is failed or succeed. And can you check if the failed user data is stored inside database or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-increment values are not intended to be consecutive. They must be unique, that's all.

If you try to decrement the auto-increment value on error, you'll create a race condition in your app. For example:

1. Your session tries to register a user. Suppose this generates id 41.
2. A second session running at the same time also tries to register a user. This generates id 42.
3. Your session returns an error, because the username you tried to register already exists. So you try to force MySQL to decrement the auto-increment.
4. A third session registers another user, using id 41. The auto-increment increments so the next registration will use id 42.
5. The next session tries to register with id 42, but this id has already been used, resulting in mass hysteria, the stock market crashes, and dogs and cats start living together.

Lesson: Don't get obsessed with id's being consecutive. They're bound to have gaps from time to time. Either an insert fails, or else you roll back a transaction, or you delete a record, etc. There are even some bugs in MySQL, that cause auto-increment to skip numbers sometimes. But there's no actual consequence to those bugs.

The way to avoid the race condition described above is that auto-increment must not decrement, even if an insert fails. It only increases. This does result in "lost" values sometimes.

I helped a company in exactly the same situation you are in, where registration of new usernames caused errors if the username was already taken. In their case, we found that someone using their site was creating a new account every day, and they were automating it. They would try "user1" and get an error, then try "user2" and "user3" and so on, until they found one that was available. But it was causing auto-increment values to be discarded, and every day the gap became larger and larger. Eventually, they ran out of integers, because the gaps were losing 1500+ id values for each registration.

(The site was an online gambling site, and we guessed that some user was trying to create daily throwaway accounts, and they had scripted a loop to register user1 through user*N*, but they start over at 1 each day, not realizing the consequences for the database.)

I recommended to them this fix: Change the registration code in their app to SELECT for the username first. If it exists, then return a friendly warning to the user and ask them to choose another name to register. This is done without attempting the INSERT.

If the SELECT finds there is no username, then try the INSERT, but be ready to handle the error anyway, in case some other session "stole" that username in the moment between the SELECT and the INSERT. Hopefully this will be rare, because it's a slim chance for someone to sneak their registration in between those two steps.

In any case, do not feel obliged to have consecutive id values.